# Google Cloud App Engine with network peering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering, peering

I'm trying to connect App Engine application to MongoDB Cloud over a peering connection.

All services in my GCP are using non-default network called "main". I've setup peering connection with terraform:

```
resource "google_compute_network_peering" "mongodb_peering" {
  name         = "mongodb-peering"
  network      = google_compute_network.main.self_link
  peer_network = "projects/${mongo-cloud-project}/global/networks/${mongo-cloud-network}"
}
```

It works as expected.

Presumably App Engine uses default VPC network.

When I'm trying to create second connection on the default network I'm getting error because of overlapping ranges. So, I've just deleted the peering with main network and set up a new one with the default network.

Still the App Engine application cannot connect to mongodb over the peering connection.

App.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F4

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
  max_concurrent_requests: 80

inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

Comment: What where the CIDR ranges of the main and default network for the first and second peering that you attempted?

Comment: @JamesS main: 10.128.0.0/9, default: 10.128.0.0/20

Comment: What's up with the downvote? Is something wrong with that question?

Comment: If you haven't solved it yet... When you said `when I'm trying to create second connection on the default network...`, what do you mean by `second connection`? My understanding you have an App Engine using the default VPC and the default VPC peering to the Atlas cloud and cannot connect from the GAE to the database?

Comment: Maybe also include info like - what flavour of gae you are using, how your app.yaml looks like, how you are accessing the database from the app, how your firewall is configured, whether you can access the same database from the VM in the VPC

Comment: You cannot have 2 or more VPC peerings that in your case, uses the same overlapping IP Ranges. This will create confusion since the routes will be created with the same priority. My suggestion for now would be as @jabbson stated, clarify your goal and provide more details and use a completely different CIDR range with the other VPC peer.

Comment: @jabbson I also thought that App Engine is using the default VPC. I deleted the "main" pearing and created one for the default VPC. The connection did not work. I've just added app.yaml.

Comment: So this is for a standard environment then. If so then the app is not using any of your networks by default, you need to use the serverless VPC access connector to connect to your VPCs.

Comment: @jabbson thanks, that helped!

Comment: @stkvtflw Were your questions answered? If so, please post it as an answer so other members with the same questions can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 or more VPC peerings that in your case, uses the same overlapping IP Ranges. This will create confusion since the routes will be created with the same priority.

And as @jabbson pointed out, the app is not using any of your networks by default. so you'll need to [create a serverless VPC access connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector) to connect your VPCs.